# creating multiple records with a single JSON post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

The following parameters are being posted

```
Parameters: {
"orig_id"=>47, 
"terms_accepted"=>true, 
"email"=>"sod@gos.co", 
"name"=>"firstname", 
"surname"=>"surname", 
"kids"=>[
  {"school"=>"Faraway", "rate"=> "89"}, 
  {"school"=>"Transfer", "rate"=> "23"}, 
  {"school"=>"Bike", "rate"=>"4"}]
 }
```

However, the rails controller action, defined as follows only creates the parent record, but not the related ones:

```
parent = params[:parent]
@parent = Parent.new(orig_id: parent['orig_id'], terms_accepted: parent['terms_accepted'], email: parent['email'], name: parent['name'], surname: parent['surname'])
@parent.save    
kids = params[:kids]
kids each do |kid|
  @kid = Kid.new(school: kid['school'], rate: kid['rate'], parent_id: @parent.id)
  @kid.save
end
```

where is the syntax wrong?

Comment: How does your model association look like? You should use (if you can change client requests) `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kids each do |kid|` actually should be `kids.each do |kid|`.

Comment: Double serving of humble pie!  Tanx!